# Is it possible to import custom Java library to a Gradle buildSrc Java class?

Tags: java, gradle

I have written a custom Gradle task in Java that generates a Java file. My task is located in the buildSrc directory of my project.
I want to extend that task, but I need to have access to my custom Java library from an another project.

```
import org.gradle.api.DefaultTask;
import org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskAction;

import my.custom.java.library.*;

public class AutoGenerateTask extends DefaultTask {

  @TaskAction
  public void generate() {
    ...
    // java code
    ...
  }

}
```

I am new to Gradle and I don't know if that is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible. You can use Gradle composite builds to include other dependencies to your build logic.

### Assumptions

Let's make some assumptions first:

**Simplified structure**

```
.
├── project-custom-lib
│   ├── build.gradle.kts
│   ├── settings.gradle.kts
│   └── src/main
│      └── java/xx/oo/Demo.java
└── project-app
    ├── buildSrc
    │   ├── build.gradle.kts
    │   └── src/main
    │      ├── java/com/example/AutoGenerateTask.java
    │      └── kotlin/com.example.java-conventions.gradle.kts
    ├── aaa
    │   ├── build.gradle.kts
    │   └── src/
    ├── bbb
    │   ├── build.gradle.kts
    │   └── src/
    └── settings.gradle.kts
```

**`project-custom-lib/build.gradle.kts`**

```gradle
...

group = "xx.oo"
```

**`project-custom-lib/settings.gradle.kts`**

```gradle
rootProject.name = "project-custom-lib"
```

**`project-custom-lib/src/main/java/xx/oo/Demo.java`**

```java
package xx.oo;

public class Demo {
    public static final String VALUE = "DEMO!";
}
```

**`project-app/settings.gradle.kts`**

```gradle
rootProject.name = "project-app"
include("aaa", "bbb")
```

**`project-app/buildSrc/src/kotlin/com.example.java-conventions.gradle.kts`**

```gradle
import com.example.AutoGenerateTask;

...

tasks.register<AutoGenerateTask>("autogen")
```

### Solution

#### Step 1: Make `buildSrc` explicit

`buildSrc` is a special folder treated as a `includeBuild` implicitly. However, it does not support including other builds for now (Gradle 7.0). Therefore, we have to break this rule first by making it explicit.

This step is easy. Just rename the folder to a name other than `buildSrc`, e.g. `build-conventions`, and create an empty `settings.gradle.kts` for it:

```bash
$ mv project-app/buildSrc project-app/build-conventions
$ touch project-app/build-conventions/settings.gralde.kts
```

Then include `build-conventions` in `project-app/settings.gradle.kts`:

```gradle
rootProject.name = "project-app"
includeBuild("build-conventions")
include("aaa", "bbb")
```

These changes should not break your project build. You can build it now:

```bash
$ cd project-app
$ ./gradlew build

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in XXs
XX actionable tasks: XX executed, XX up-to-date

# If you write some tests inside build-conventions, you definitely need this.
$ ./gradlew -p build-conventions build

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in XXs
XX actionable tasks: XX executed, XX up-to-date
```

#### Step 2: Make `project-custom-lib`'s classes resolvable in `build-conventions`

Actually, Gradle did describe how to do this in [Composite Builds](https://docs.gradle.org/7.2/userguide/composite_builds.html):

> By default, Gradle will configure each included build in order to determine the dependencies it can provide. The algorithm for doing this is very simple: Gradle will inspect the group and name for the projects in the included build, and substitute project dependencies for any external dependency matching `${project.group}:${project.name}`.

So let's include it first by adding this line to `project-app/build-conventions/settings.gradle.kts`:

```gradle
includeBuild("../../project-custom-lib")
```

Then add the dependency in `project-app/build-conventions/build.gradle.kts`:

```gradle
...

dependencies {
    implementation("xx.oo:project-custom-lib")
}
```

Now you should be able to import it in your code:

```java
...

import xx.oo.Demo;

public class AutoGenerateTask extends DefaultTask {
    @TaskAction
    public void generate() {
        System.out.println(Demo.VALUE);

        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. It wasn't exactly the solution I was looking for, because I didn't want to use composite builds. The custom task has to stay within buildSrc and the external library is a jar file. However you helped me find the solution. I thought that, I only had to include the library dependency inside the application's build.gradle.kts file, but I also had to do that inside buildSrc's build.gradle.kts.